# Create Virtual Machine Deployment Azure REST API

Tags: rest, api, azure

```
        String cloudServiceDeployment = "imagevmtest";
        url = String.format("https://management.core.windows.net/%s/services/hostedservices/%s/deployments", subscriptionId, cloudServiceDeployment);
        String requestBody2 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Deployment xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\"><Name>190bed4a</Name><DeploymentSlot>Production</DeploymentSlot><Label>190bed4a</Label><RoleList><Role><RoleName>SuseOpenVm_rolec8fc</RoleName><RoleType>PersistentVMRole</RoleType><ConfigurationSets><ConfigurationSet><ConfigurationSetType>LinuxProvisioningConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType><HostName>SuseOpenVm_rolec8fc</HostName><UserName>anandsrinivasan</UserName><UserPassword>Cloud360</UserPassword><DisableSshPasswordAuthentication>false</DisableSshPasswordAuthentication></ConfigurationSet><ConfigurationSet><ConfigurationSetType>NetworkConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType><DisableSshPasswordAuthentication>false</DisableSshPasswordAuthentication><InputEndpoints><InputEndpoint><LocalPort>22</LocalPort><Name>SSH</Name><Port>22</Port><Protocol>TCP</Protocol></InputEndpoint></InputEndpoints></ConfigurationSet></ConfigurationSets><OSVirtualHardDisk><MediaLink>https://2xportalvhds7jsf9ncknn4s.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/imagevmtest-imagevmtest-2016-11-10.vhd</MediaLink><SourceImageName>imagevmtest-imagevmtest-2016-11-10.vhd</SourceImageName></OSVirtualHardDisk><RoleSize>Small</RoleSize></Role></RoleList><VirtualNetworkName>anand360NW</VirtualNetworkName></Deployment>";

        int deployResponseCode = processPostRequest(new URL(url),requestBody2.getBytes(), "application/xml", keyStorePath, keyStorePassword);
        System.out.println(deployResponseCode);
```

I am using the above code and trying to create a virtual machine in my  Azure. But still getting error 400. Can you guys guide me how to create a vm in my Azure account via REST API?

Comment: I would like to ask you what is the purpose of trying to use the raw REST API to create Azure resources? Have you tried some of the alternatives?

Comment: @MilanNankov I am planning on something that can let users create vm on the Azure automatically once they created an account under my website. What are the alternatives? Can you provides some steps? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now a direct anwer to your question but I will offer some alternatives that might be better for your scenario.

Having to deal with generating the whole XML is quite difficult and error prone. The REST API is as low level as it gets on Azure. My suggestion is to try some of the API/Tools that are built ontop of the REST API like [PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/) and [Azure CLI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-azure-resource-manager/).

The best option, if you are using .NET, is to use [Management Libraries for .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722415.aspx). The original Management Libraries are a bit cumbersome to use but there is a new and improved version in the works using fluent API and from what I have seen so far, it is awesome! Here is the introductory blog post - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/simpler-azure-management-libraries-for-net/

To summarize, I think that it is best if you could spare yourself the trouble of working with the raw REST API and use some of the wrappers instead.

Let me know that you think.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help. I will get back to here ASAP. Give me some time to develop and figure it out. I appreciate that you could give me some advises here. =)

Comment: I can create a vm now using Azure CLI. Thank you. And now I have another question, the vm is manually created by using azure CLI. Is there any step to automatically create a vm using Azure CLI?

Comment: Cloud you elaborate a bit on your last comment. What do you mean by "automatically"? In response to some event or? You have mentioned your website so you probably want to creates VMs when a user is registered. Is you site a ASP.NET application or you are using some other technology?

Comment: Now, Azure CLI is a command prompt thing, so when I need to create a vm, I need to manually key in everything. My site is a PHP I guess. So is there any way to create vm automatically. I am trying to use Visual Studio now but I face some problem whenever I try to login. I guess it is the single sign-on reply uri thing.